# Delete data from FMDB using an array in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, sqlite, fmdb

I am trying to delete multiple rows from database. Currently, I have an array which consists of all the row id's which i want to delete. But i cannot seem to find a suitable code for it

```
  func deleteMultiple(Id:[Int]) -> NSMutableArray {
    sharedInstance.databese!.open()

    var i:Int = Id.count
    print(Id, i)
    let resultSet:FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.databese!.executeQuery("DELETE FROM Info WHERE Id = ?", withArgumentsIn: Id)

    let itemInfo:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray ()
    if (resultSet != nil)
    {
        while resultSet.next() {

            let item:Tbl_Info = Tbl_Info()
            item.Id = Int(resultSet.int(forColumn: "Id"))
            item.Name = String(resultSet.string(forColumn: "Name")!)
            item.LastName = String(resultSet.string(forColumn: "LastName")!)

            itemInfo.add(item)
        }
    }

    sharedInstance.databese!.close()
    return itemInfo

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your query in a queue it will not freeze your database.

if anything fails during the transaction FMDB Provides the rollback functionality.
Look at the sample code.

```
sharedInstance.databese.dbQueue.inTransaction { db, rollback in
     idArray.forEach {id in
     do {
            let resultSet:FMResultSet! = try db.executeQuery("DELETE FROM Info WHERE Id = ?", withArgumentsIn: Id)
            //Do whatever with your resultSet
        } catch {
            //Error occured during deleting from database.
            rollback.pointee = true
        }
     }
  }
```